# PyQGIS: What objects need to be destroyed in a custom expression

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5, qgis-custom-function

I'm using a custom (PyQGIS) function in expressions to make little detailed minimaps around each feature in a layer, and store it in the layer (gpkg) as a png.

My code works but makes QGIS (3.12) unstable, leading to eventual hangs after I use the custom expression in Field Calculator or forms. My hypothesis is that I'm foolishly relying on garbage collection to recycle some `Qgs...` objects that I need to destroy myself. Can anyone advise which ones? I've got a `QgsMapSettings`, a `QgsCoordinateTransform`, a `QgsMapRendererJob`, `QByteArray` and `QBuffer` any of which might be tripping me up. Since it's sporadic and sometimes freezes some time after my expression does its thing, it's time consuming to track it down experimentally...

```py
def minimap_as_blob(geom,radius, xpixels, ypixels, feature, parent, context):
    # Set up map settings for the minimap based on the mapcanvas
    ms= QgsMapSettings()
    cms = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()
    destCrs = cms.destinationCrs()
    ms.setLayers(cms.layers())
    ms.setDestinationCrs(destCrs)
    ms.setBackgroundColor(cms.backgroundColor())
    ms.setExpressionContext(cms.expressionContext())

    # geom is in CRS of its layer, transform to CRS of map
    layer_id = context.variable('layer_id')
    sourceCrs = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().get(layer_id).crs()
    if destCrs != sourceCrs:
        tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(sourceCrs, cms.destinationCrs(), QgsProject.instance())
        geom.transform(tr)
    ms.setOutputSize(QSize(xpixels, ypixels))
    # radius is size of buffer around geom, in destination CRS units
    bbox = geom.buffer(radius,1).boundingBox()
    ms.setExtent(bbox) 

    # make map as a sequential job
    job = QgsMapRendererSequentialJob(ms)
    job.start()
    job.waitForFinished()
    img = job.renderedImage()

    # return the image as a QByteArray
    ba = QByteArray()
    buffer=QBuffer(ba)
    buffer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    img.save(buffer, "PNG")
    return ba
```

**Editing to add:** The article at https://machinekoder.com/how-to-not-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-using-python-qt/ adds to my nervousness about relying on garbage collection, since there is apparently both Python's and Qt's destruction to worry about. It seems certain objects may need to be Qt5-`.deleteLater()`-ed rather than Python-`del`ed. I'm really not sure how everything (including Qt's event loop and QGIS's job rendering) interact in a custom function invoked in an expression in Field Calculator or in a Form (where it currently lives inside a QML Widget!)